# Java Generics for using <T> methods not defined in parent class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, extends

I have a method which is as follows

```
private <T extends GenericObject>void printStatus(final T result) {
    System.out.println("Status", result.getStatus());
    System.out.println("GenericStatus", result.getGenericStatus());
    System.out.println("GenericMessage", result.getGenericMessage());

}
```

The getGenericStatus and getGenericMessage methods are defined in the genericObject parent class. However, the getStatus method is defined in the child classes that extends GenericObject and the return type of getStatus is an enum which is differently defined for each child class. Such as

```
public class A extends GenericObject {

      /** Enum Astatus. */
      private AStatus status;

      AStatus getStatus() {
           return status;
      }
 }

public class B extends GenericObject {

      /** Enum Bstatus. */
      private BStatus status;

      BStatus getStatus() {
           return status;
      }
 }
```

Problem is result.getstatus() in the printStatus is giving compile error. What will be the easiest way to fix this within the printStatus method without refactoring a lot of code?

Comment: Make GenericObject an abstract class. It fits your requirements clearly.

Comment: Please format your post. Frankly, I found it difficult to parse your syntax, and names of the methods of classes. It's hard to read it.

Comment: Isn't the name *`GenericObject`* a misnomer for a class that declares zero type parameters?

Answer (score 6):

There is no point in making method generic in `T` when `T` appears in only one place.  Instead, you can just write:

```
private void printStatus(GenericObject result) { ... }
```

Type variables mainly add value only when they appear in multiple places, such as:

```
<T> T choose(boolean condition, T ifTrue, T ifFalse) { 
    return condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse;
}
```

or

```
<T> List<T> toList(Set<T> set) { ... }
```

because they express actual constraints between multiple parameters or between parameter and return.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to push the declaration of `getStatus` up to the `GenericObject` class:

```java
public class GenericObject {
    public abstract Object getStatus();

    // Other methods...
}
```

The other classes won't have to change since subclass are allowed to specialize the return type of a parent's method.